# Can i add imageview or textview a regular button?

Tags: android

i am curios about that, in proper button can i add a imageView or textview  in xml? İs it possible? if it is possible how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: A Button isn't a ViewGroup, so you can't add any children to it. You can however add text, add compound drawables and change the background. Perhaps you can elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: but background is ninepatch so key is seen bad when is streched.

Comment: What do you mean by "seen bad"? As far as I can tell your 9patch does not scale the key, but only the surrounding areas. If you really can't  accomplish what you're looking for using an out-of-the-box widget, I suggest you take a look at [creating a custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) (more specifically, read the Compound Controls section - e.g. you could combine an ImageView and TextView in a layout and have the result act like a button).

Answer (score 0):

I'm nt sure about adding an image view to a button, but you could just use a view, and fill that the approriate images and text.

Comment: i update my question.I want to do that.Do you know how can i do that? and i must write someting between the key